# How Do I Fix (TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable)?

Tags: json

if ("id" in request.json and "pw" in request.json and "pin" in request.json):

That Is the line that has problem.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that `request.json` is None. The `in` keyword checks if the value appears in a sequence, but you cannot iterate over `None`. Print out the request and verify that it contains a field called json.

Comment: If i share you the src can you fix it for me??

Comment: Edit your question with the code and I'll take a look.